# how come this summation after produkt?

Tags: exponential-function

I am really stuck in this step. I hope, the context does not matter here, so i didnot provide what this is about. I am trying to get ML-Estimator. but the problem is, as i see in my textbook, how they changed the produkt to summation, why it became $\sum$

$$L(a;X)=\prod_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2}a \cdot exp(-a\cdot|x_i|) = \frac{1}{2^n}a^n\cdot exp(-a\sum_{i=1}^{n}|x_i|)$$

THANKS for help!

Comment: $\exp(a)\exp(b)=\exp(a+b)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a property of the exponential function. Indeed $\exp(a+b)=\exp(a)\cdot\exp(b)$ and so induction shows that
$$
\prod_{i=1}^n\exp(a_i)=\exp\left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\right).
$$
Use this with $a_i=-\vartheta|x_i|$.

Comment: oh yeah, this is the point, thanks Stefan

Answer (score 2):

$$\prod_{i=1}^n\left(a\cdot\mathrm e^{u_i}\right)=a^n\cdot\prod_{i=1}^n\mathrm e^{u_i}=a^n\cdot\exp\left(\sum_{i=1}^nu_i\right)$$

Comment: This is the great disadvantage of adding no explanation about the problem you have with the question: answerers cannot know what is troubling you. Perhaps André's comment is all you need, how are we supposed to know? See Edit.

Comment: ((Comment by the OP cancelled after I answered it.))